# Prestashop cart rule with free shipping not works

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have a site in prestashop (version 1.7.6.9), I created a cart rule that applies a 30% discount on the whole cart and also free shipping:

[image]

but when I enter the code it only applies percentage discount and not free shipping:

[image]

I've tried removing the percentage discount, leaving only the free shipping and in this case it takes away the shipping cost, but I need both discounts, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by editing the file /src/Adapter/Presenter/Cart/CartPresenter.php and adding this function:

```
private function getShippingDisplayValue($cart, $shippingCost)
    {
        $shippingDisplayValue = '';
        // if one of the applied cart rules have free shipping, then the shipping display value is 'Free'
        foreach ($cart->getCartRules() as $rule) {
            if ($rule['free_shipping'] && !$rule['carrier_restriction']) {
                return $this->translator->trans('Free', [], 'Shop.Theme.Checkout');
            }
        }
        if ($shippingCost != 0) {
            $shippingDisplayValue = $this->priceFormatter->format($shippingCost);
        } else {
            $defaultCountry = null;
            if (isset(Context::getContext()->cookie->id_country)) {
                $defaultCountry = new Country((int) Context::getContext()->cookie->id_country);
            }
            $deliveryOptionList = $cart->getDeliveryOptionList($defaultCountry);
            if (count($deliveryOptionList) > 0) {
                foreach ($deliveryOptionList as $option) {
                    foreach ($option as $currentCarrier) {
                        if (isset($currentCarrier['is_free']) && $currentCarrier['is_free'] > 0) {
                            $shippingDisplayValue = $this->translator->trans('Free', [], 'Shop.Theme.Checkout');
                            break 2;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $shippingDisplayValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the way discounts including shipping works with PS 1.7 - Shipping price is always shown in order total , but shipping cost is being summed and subtracted in the "discount" row.

If you do the math you will notice the screenshot is correct, as discount is summing up 30% on price (32.70) + shipping (7.00) resulting in a 39.70 total discount.

Comment: How can I then write in place of the shipping cost the words "Free"?